# why am I getting 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 0

Tags: actionscript-3

Beginning issue: I am continuously getting an error 1136 at var timer:Timer=new Timer(10000,1);. I am not sure if its a computer error or what. I know you put (delay, and then time interval) for Timer, but it still gives me the error message.

update: I uploaded the whole code from the original post to see if anyone could find any errors. My Timers should be correct but I am still getting the error 1136 on my program and it won't even run. When I do take out the timers, the code works perfectly fine. 
Is there any other way to. implement a timer to make the game stop and say game over?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.*; 

public class Duckhunt extends MovieClip 
{
    private var player1:Player;
    private var counter:Number;
    private var points:Number;
    private var cursor:Cursor;
    private var duckArmy:Vector.<Duck1>;
    private var duckArmy2:Vector.<Duck2>;
    private var duckCounter:Number;
    private var duckCounter2:Number;
    private var count:Number=10;
    private var timer:Timer;
    //var countDownDec:Number=1;
    //private var myTimer:Timer=new Timer(0,count);


    public function Duckhunt() 
    {
        //# constructor code

        // creates a new five-second Timer 
        var timer:Timer=new Timer(10000,1);

        //add event listner to timer
        timer.start();

        //starts the timer
        //myTimer.start();

        player1=new Player();
        player1.x = 375; player1.y = 400; addChild(player1);

        //cursor crosshair
        cursor= new Cursor();
        cursor.x = 400; cursor.y = 200; addChild(cursor);

        //add enemy
        duckArmy=new Vector.<Duck1>();

        for(var i:Number = 0; i < 30; i++)  
        {
            var duck:Duck1 = new Duck1(400,0);
            duckArmy.push(duck);
            duck.y = 450;
            stage.addChild(duck);
            duck.gotoAndPlay("fly");
            duck.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitEnemy);

        }//end duck1 army

        //add second second enemy
        duckArmy2=new Vector.<Duck2>();

        for(var j:Number=0;j<30;j++)
        {
            var duck2:Duck2 = new Duck2(0,400);
            duckArmy2.push(duck2);
            duck2.x = -900;
            stage.addChild(duck2);
            duck2.gotoAndPlay("fly");
            duck2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitEnemy);
        }//end duck2 army

        duckCounter = duckCounter2 =counter = points = 0;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameMovement);

    }//end constructor


}//end class


}//end package
```

Comment: I'm rusty with AS3. Does its syntax allow to call functions without parantheses? Try `timer.start();` instead. `timer.start;` would mean you're trying to manipulate a variable called `start`, which doesn't exist. Even if you don't assign a new value, it should still call the setter function and try to pass _something_  which might be the problem.

Comment: And I think my suspicions might be correct, [according to the documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f57.html) `If you are calling a function with no parameters, you !!must!! use an empty pair of parentheses.` (emphasis mine)

Comment: I tried with timer.start(); and it still gives me the error code. Thats what I thought first but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: I think it could just be a program error or glitch. It should execute the timer and not show an error.

Comment: Turn debugging on and narrow down the error to a certain line of code. The provided sample does not seem to have any syntax errors (even **timer.start;** is not a **syntax** error), so that error of yours must be happening somewhere else.

Comment: The program runs when I comment the timers, so Its hard for me to believe its the rest of the code. should I try to post the whole code on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've declared your `:Timer` object as a *public* or *private* variable:

```
private var timer:Timer;
```

There's no need for declaring yet another new variable (with same name) in later functions;

```
var timer:Timer=new Timer(10000,1); //creates a new 2nd var.. causes error..
timer.start();
```

Shoud be:

```
timer = new Timer (10000,1); //uses existing private var
timer.start();
```

Also note:

That `timer` **variable** name is too similar to the `Timer` **datatype** name,  consider changing the name's spelling to avoid "clashing" with built-in system names. Never do `var int :int = 0;`.

Try naming as `_timer :Timer;` or even `myTimer :Timer;`

Comment: great! Thank you!

Comment: @NewCoder0422 If this answer solved all the problems posed in your question, you should mark the answer, also you may upvote it as a common courtesy. Both actions will up the rating of the person answered and help other people to see this person as a reliable and helpful.